# How to insert and display an image in Android?

Tags: java, android

I want to insert and display an image. But I have some error. Why I have an error at word "with"?

```
UsersRef.child(currentUserID).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener(){
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot){
        if(dataSnapshot.exists()){
            String image = dataSnapshot.child("Tuition Image").getValue().toString();

            Picasso.with(AddAdsActivity.this).load(image).placeholder(R.drawable.camera).into(TuitionImage);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError){

    }
});
```

Comment: what error is "with" you getting ?

Comment: I cannot run the apps sir

Comment: **Why I have an error at "with" word?** what error you getting ? please add more information

Comment: Cannot resole method with '(com.addaj,mobileapps.AddAdsActivity)'

Comment: Where you have written that code ?? In class  AddAdsActivity ??

Comment: Please create a [mcve]

Comment: Yes the code is in class AddAdsActivity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace this line:

```
Picasso.with(AddAdsActivity.this).load(image).placeholder(R.drawable.camera).into(TuitionImage);
```

With this:

```
Picasso.get().load(image).placeholder(R.drawable.camera).into(TuitionImage);
```

And that's it.. Your error will be solved.

Comment: Thank you! You are a very helpful person.

Comment: Feels great to see some comments like this.. :)